# How to count each list length in K?

Tags: k

On a page https://shakti.com/tutorial/ I've found the solution, it is

```
#:'z / counts each list
```

The same solution was mentioned in https://code.kx.com/v2/learn/startingkdb/language/ by switching to k mode in q:

```
q) #:'(1 2;"abc")            / equivalent k expression
2 3
```

Why this expression `#:'` counts the number?

- `#` counts
- `'` is an `each` Adverb
- but what `:` means in this case? This is not an assignment, right?

Comment: "While you get k4 with KDB+, k4 is proprietary to Kx and no documentation is available." (Kona github repo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a page http://www.math.bas.bg/bantchev/place/k.html they mentioned that:

> `:` within `|:` is used to force the verb `|` to be interpreted as a monad,
>   as by default ambiguities are resolved in favour of dyads

Also here http://web.archive.org/web/20050504070651/http://www.kx.com/technical/documents/kreflite.pdf noted about the same:

> Note that whenever Each is applied to the monad of a primitive verb,
>   as in `!:'` for Enumerate-Each, the monadic case must be made explicit
>   by modifying the verb with colon. The dyadic case is assumed if no
>   modifier is present.

And that's make sense:

```
/ # want's to act as dyadic verb
  #' (1 2; "abc")
#'[(1 2;"abc")]

/ make use of dyadic # behavior
  5 6 #' (1 2; "abc")
(1 2 1 2 1;"abcabc")

/ monadic case
  #:' (1 2; "abc")
2 3
```